# Android-based remote software to log in to OSX desktop?

Tags: vnc, macos, remote-access

I have an Android phone that I'd like to use to control an iMac running Snow Leopard.  Like everything else they do, it seems Apple has their own take on how a VNC server should work, so their "remote desktop" does not seem to play nice with e.g. AndroidVNC.

I've tried some other stuff like gPad and gMote, both of which have dedicated server-side software.  They work fine, but I can't run them at *boot* time, only at login -- so if I'm not logged in to start with, I have to pull out the mouse and keyboard to switch users / log in, which defeats the purpose.  If I can "daemonize" the server software for one of those packages, great, but I'd be surprised since they have a tray icon / UI to control them.  I've looked into launchd a little bit but I'm not sure I can take an arbitrary user-space / GUI-having binary and run it "headless", as a system account.

I don't strictly need the display-back -- this is more for a home theater kind of setup -- but I wouldn't *mind*.  I guess my questions are either a) can I run something on my phone that will use the built-in remoting service (from boot time!) or b) can I make one of the existing server applications (gPad, gMote, whatever) run at boot time?

ETA: Free is better, obviously, but feel free to mention for-pay stuff, I guess.  And like I said, this is mostly for home-theater stuff, so wifi/LAN-only solutions are not a problem.

Comment: Does it need to be a free solution? And are you doing this just on your local LAN or do you also want to be able to control your computer from anywhere you're online with your phone?

Comment: Gee, AndroidVNC has worked fine for me with both Leopard and Snow Leopard, both with the built-in VNC server and with Vine Server. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with TeamViewer, but thanks for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 4):

You should try [LogMeIn - Ignition for Android](https://secure.logmein.com/welcome/android/).  I find it much faster than VNC when accessing my Macbook from my Windows PC.  I'd image it works just as well with Android.

Answer (score 1):

[PocketCloud](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.wyse.pocketcloudfree&hl=en) is excellent and free to use for one computer at a time.